# How to return blank and not 0, while mapping through a 2D array using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multidimensional-array, filter

Right now, the code does divides each element by 100, so I can get it in the correct % format.
However, when the element iterated is blank, it gives me 0 while this would have to be blank and I can't seem to make it right:

The data in a 2D array:

```
[
 ["MARLEY SC35-45 PIPE CLIP PVCu","82",1,0,11.96,-68],
 ["MARLEY SC35-45 PIPE CLIP PVCu","110",1,0,10.02,],
 ["MARLEY SC35-45 PIPE CLIP PVCu","160",1,0,32.62,-68]
]
```

The code I'm running returns `0`, but this would have to be blank.

```
let dataLab3 = dataLab.map(function (v) { return [v[5]/100] })
```

Current result:

```
-68
-0
-68
```

..while it should be:

```
-68

-68
```

I'm not sure where I'd apply a `filter` in this case.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add a check in the map to see if it has a value either with a truthy check

```
return v[5] ? [v[5]/100] : '';
```

or check if it is undefined if the value can be zero.

```js
const dataLab = [
  ["MARLEY SC35-45 PIPE CLIP PVCu","82",1,0,11.96,-68],
  ["MARLEY SC35-45 PIPE CLIP PVCu","110",1,0,10.02,],
  ["MARLEY SC35-45 PIPE CLIP PVCu","160",1,0,32.62,-68]
];

const dataLab3 = dataLab.map(function (v) {
  return v[5] !== undefined ? [v[5]/100] : undefined;
});

console.log(dataLab3);
```

return whatever you want in the second part of the ternary operator.

Comment: I guess we need to return ```[""]```, or ```[undefined]``` so that we can keep it as a 2D Array. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If v[5] does not exist, then return "" (or `null`):

```
let dataLab3 = dataLab.map(v => v[5] ? [v[5]/100] : "" )
```

Comment: There a ```}```, but other than that...thank you!

Comment: Ah, indeed, removed the extra `}`